# Package pgf Error: No shape C_1 is known

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I was trying to compile a latex code of a graph. However, I got many errors. It shows me Package pgf Error: No shape C_1 is known. The error appears for all the nodes in the Graph.

Here is the code I used:

```
     \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\begin{document}
% Define layers
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

% The scale option is useful for adjusting spacing between nodes.
% Note that this works best when straight lines are used to connect
% the nodes.
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',scale=0.8]
    % set node style
    \tikzstyle{n} = [draw,shape=circle,minimum size=2em,
                        inner sep=0pt,fill=red!20]
    \begin{dot2tex}[dot,tikz,codeonly,styleonly,options=-s -tmath]
        digraph G  {
            node [style="n"];
            A_1 -> B_1; A_1 -> B_2; A_1 -> B_3;
            B_1 -> C_1; B_1 -> C_2;
            B_2 -> C_2; B_2 -> C_3;
            B_3 -> C_3; B_3 -> C_4;
        }
    \end{dot2tex}
    % annotations
    \node[left=1em] at (C_1.west)  (l3) {Level 3};
    \node at (l3 |- B_1) (l2){Level 2};
    \node at (l3 |- A_1) (l1) {Level 1};
    % Draw lines to separate the levels. First we need to calculate
    % where the middle is.
    \path (l3) -- coordinate (l32) (l2) -- coordinate (l21) (l1);
    \draw[dashed] (C_1 |- l32) -- (l32 -| C_4);
    \draw[dashed] (C_1 |- l21) -- (l21 -| C_4);
    \draw[<->,red] (A_1) to[out=-120,in=90] (C_2);
    % Highlight the A_1 -> B_1 -> C_2 path. Use layers to draw
    % behind everything.
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \draw[rounded corners=2em,line width=3em,blue!20,cap=round]
                (A_1.center) -- (B_1.west) -- (C_2.center);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requisites:

- The program [`dot2tex`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/dot2tex) needs to be installed.
- Option `-shell-escape` or `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX) for the LaTeX run.

Then package [`dot2texi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dot2texi) converts the dot data to TeX code with TikZ commands in
file `\jobname-dot2tex-fig1.tex` (see the package [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/dot2texi/dot2texi.pdf)):

```
%%
\node (A_1) at (147bp,162bp) [n] {$A_1$};
  \node (C_1) at (30bp,18bp) [n] {$C_1$};
  \node (C_3) at (186bp,18bp) [n] {$C_3$};
  \node (C_2) at (108bp,18bp) [n] {$C_2$};
  \node (C_4) at (264bp,18bp) [n] {$C_4$};
  \node (B_1) at (69bp,90bp) [n] {$B_1$};
  \node (B_2) at (147bp,90bp) [n] {$B_2$};
  \node (B_3) at (225bp,90bp) [n] {$B_3$};
  \draw [->] (B_1) -- (C_1);
  \draw [->] (B_3) -- (C_4);
  \draw [->] (B_3) -- (C_3);
  \draw [->] (B_1) -- (C_2);
  \draw [->] (A_1) -- (B_1);
  \draw [->] (A_1) -- (B_3);
  \draw [->] (A_1) -- (B_2);
  \draw [->] (B_2) -- (C_2);
  \draw [->] (B_2) -- (C_3);
%
```

Then `C_1` and the other nodes are defined and the example runs without error.

> [image: Result]